# How to improve this piano sound

Tags: vst, fl-studio, piano

I play the piano and use FL with Keyscape to record my songs/cover.. But the sound seems very cold, expecially in mid frequencies, so:could you please help me to understand what I should do to improve it? Thanks :)
 This is an example of the sound I obtain (no EQ, only factory settings of Keyscape) :

Comment: What's the problem with using an EQ?

Comment: As I read it, the audio is „raw“, i.e. without any further post-processing, yet. // Adding the audio effect „chorus“ may make the recording sound more interesting. Also consider applying „room effects“, like „middle sized room“.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the issue is the recorded piano which doesn’t match your taste. The Keyscape piano is a Yamaha C7 which I consider quite bright (too bright according to my tastes).

Some other virtual pianos are mellower (Hamburg Steinway, CFX, Bechstein, Bösendorfer…) I have many of them, don’t use much the different C7 I have. The Bechstein Digital Grand has a bright/mellow knob and I like to set it more on the mellow side.

Perhaps also a too dry sound can be enhanced by a reverb, but it won’t help if what you don’t like is the brightness.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

He goes through a whole bunch of different effects to make a sampled piano sound better. It's in Ableton but FL has equivalent filters and effects.